# Using watson developer cloud with react native

Tags: react-native, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm trying to integrate my already created IBM Watson chatbot into my react native mobile application. Any time I import `watson-developer-cloud` I get an error saying that Node.js standard libraries such as stream are not compatible with Expo. I've seen other people using watson services to create speech to text apps. I don't understand how they are using the services without the `watson-developer-cloud` package. I've seen some community created packages such as `react-native-watson` that supposedly can make this happen, but I can't get any of it to work. Is there any way I can make this work or is it impossible? Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you with some path, for sure you can use React Native to built the UI for your app. But also you need the back-end and communicate with Watson API. (If you want you can use just the `fetch` from react native, but I really recommend you don't do that if your app will grow with time.

I really recommend you take a look at [Watson developer Cloud](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud), and use the [Assistant Simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-simple) to understand the backend with Node.js. Also try to check the Watson Assistant API documentation.

For summary, you'll create one server with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [`express`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html), and create routers in your backend, with theses routes, you gonna use fetch from React native to send HTTP requests to your routes, your backend will call Watson Assistant API and answer. Your fetch will get this response and show that to the user in your U.

**Obs.:** You can use any language in the backend and Watson Developer Cloud has a lot of examples using Watson Assistant with [Java](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/master/assistant), [Python](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/develop/examples/assistant_v1.py), etc.

- See the Official [Watson Assistant API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/node.html?node) documentation.
- See the Official use of [Fetch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) in React Native.